# How can I insert data in tables with ternary relation in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have these two tables:

- `order` (order_id[primary key, auto increment in MY SQL], bill, payment_method, quantity, date);
- `order_medicine` (order_id, med_name, customer_id)

because `order` is related to `customer` and `medicines`. Can you tell me how can I insert order data in these two tables without getting redundant tuples in table 1 (`order`)?

Comment: I don't understand. First you described the `order` and `order_medicine` tables, but then you say it's related to `customer` and `medicines`. Which tables are you really asking about? And why do you get redundant rows?

Comment: You need to post the code that isn't working.

Comment: It sounds like you have 4 tables.

Comment: It looks like `order_medicine` is related to `order` , `customer` and `medicine` and you're also saying the `order` is related to `customer` and `medicine` one of the two should not be true. I suggest you drop the ternary relationship. `order_medicine` should relate to `order` and `medicine`, and `order` should relate to `customer` (only) therefore order medicine would be indirectly related to customer.

Comment: First you insert the order into the `order` table. You use `LAST_INSERT_ID()` to get the `order_id` that was assigned to it. Then you insert all the medicines into `order_medicine`, using the ID you get from `LAST_INSERT_ID()` to relate them to the order.

Comment: I actually have three tables: 
1)Medicine(name,stock,date_of_manufacture,date_of_expiry,price)
2)Customer(customer_id,name,address,contact)
3)Order(order_id,bill,order_date,paymnet_methood)
Customer has 1 to Many relation and order and medicine has many   to many relation, therefore we made the relational table with primary keys of these three tables , order_medicine (order_id, med_name, customer_id).
Can you tell me how can I insert order data in the two tables ie order and order_medicine.

Comment: Why is `customer_id` in the `order_medicine` table? That should be in the `order` table, since the order should be for a single customer.

Comment: And why is `quantity` in the `order` table? That should be in `order_medicine`, since each medicine could have a different quantity.

Comment: LAST_INSERT_ID() is a built-in function? 
Actually that is the total quantity that is to be ordered, however we will add individual quantity in order_medicine table as well.

Comment: And yes I was confused about placing customer_id. Thank you so much for clearing this out